# Receive money in US as non-US resident?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax

Hey so I'm currently working for a US LLC and I'm exploring some payment options, since receiving a wire transfer in my country is a hassle. Say I open a US bank account and receive money, would I pay tax and how much? Would my employer pay taxes? I'm not a US citizen and I don't live there, so I'd be spending all my money abroad.

Comment: "Say I open a US bank account" Easier said than done. At some point, you're going to have to get the money into your bank so you can spend it, and that's almost certainly going to involve a wire transfer.

Comment: @RupertMorrish probably missunderstood me - getting a wire transfer to my local bank account is a pain. If I had a US one, it would be US bank account > US bank account transfer. And if I have a card to go with my US account, I don't need to wire it to myself - I can just use the card and spend directly from that one

Answer (score 1):

Given that receiving a wire transfer is "a hassle" I assume that either the LLC you're working for is rather small/new, or the country you're working in has few (economic) ties to the US.

You could go old school and use a service like Western Union (which has a fairly large world-wide presence). Some more modern equivalents are PayPal, Transferwise, MoneyGram, OFX, etc. (no endorsement given or implied). Or you could go very modern and use Bitcoin (or BitcoinCash, Litecoin, Ethereum, ... if the fees are too high) as one of their raison d'êtres is borderless transfer of value (though you might want to convert back into your local currency quickly to avoid the volatility).

I'm pretty sure the manner in which your paid has no bearing on who (between the US and your home country) is going to claim taxes on it, unless the presence of a bank account is used as evidence in a residency test. The advantage of a US bank account is that you could decouple the payment from the transfer (e.g. get paid weekly but only deal with wire transfer hassle on an as-needed basis, and you might have more visibility/control in the process if you own both ends).